"Partial limits" and rates of convergence
As per Wikipedia,

A sequence $(x_{n})$ that converges to $L$ is said to have order of convergence $ q\geq 1$ and rate of convergence $\mu\in (0,1)$ if
\begin{equation}\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }{\frac {\left|x_{n+1}-L\right|}{\left|x_{n}-L\right|^{q}}}=\mu\end{equation}

Now let $(x_{n})$ and $(y_{n})$ be two sequences that converge to the same limit $L$, such that $(x_{n})$ is increasing and $(y_{n})$ is decreasing (I came across this topic while studying the arithmetic-geometric mean AGM and other types of mean interations). Many authors study the following limit instead:
\begin{equation}\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }{\frac {y_{n+1}-x_{n+1}}{\left(y_{n}-x_{n}\right)^{q}}}\end{equation}
For example, some conclude from $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }{\frac {a_{n+1}-b_{n+1}}{\left(a_{n}-b_{n}\right)^{2}}} = \frac{1}{8\ AGM(a_0,b_0)}$ that the AGM iteration converges quadratically.
From my own calculations, I assume that
\begin{equation}\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }{\frac {y_{n+1}-x_{n+1}}{\left(y_{n}-x_{n}\right)^{q}}} = \frac{1}{q} \lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }{\frac {y_{n+1}-L}{\left(y_{n}-L\right)^{q}}} \end{equation} under the given assumptions. For $q = 1$, this would give
\begin{equation}\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }{\frac {y_{n+1}-x_{n+1}}{y_{n}-x_{n}}} = \lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }{\frac {y_{n+1}-L}{y_{n}-L}} \end{equation} which is wrong in general (taking "partial" limits), but presumably correct under the given assumptions.
Is my assumption correct? If so, can it be generalised?

To clarify the question. Are you asking if $(x_{n})$ and $(y_{n})$ be two sequences that converge to the same limit $L$, such that $(x_{n})$ is increasing and $(y_{n})$ is decreasing then
\begin{equation}\lim {n\rightarrow \infty }{\frac {y{n+1}-x_{n+1}}{\left(y_{n}-x_{n}\right)^{q}}} = \frac{1}{q} \lim {n\rightarrow \infty }{\frac {y{n+1}-L}{\left(y_{n}-L\right)^{q}}} \end{equation}
for some (what ?) $q$, especially, for $q = 1$?

A converging sequence may not have any order of convergence. E.g. consider $x_n=(1/2)^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}$, that is, $$1,;\frac12,;\frac12,;\frac14,;\frac14,;\frac18,;\frac18,;\frac1{16},;\frac1{16},;\frac1{32},;\cdots;.$$ If $n=2m$ is even, then $$\frac{|x_{n+1}-0|}{|x_n-0|^q}=\frac{(1/2)^m}{(1/2)^{mq}}=(1/2)^{(1-q)m};$$ if $n=2m+1$ is odd, then $$\frac{|x_{n+1}-0|}{|x_n-0|^q}=\frac{(1/2)^{m+1}}{(1/2)^{mq}}=(1/2)^{(1-q)m+1};$$ so as $n\to\infty$ or equivalently $m=\lfloor n/2\rfloor\to\infty$, both of these diverge if $q>1$,

and if $q=1$ then the ratio $x_{n+1}/x_n$ alternates between $1$ and $1/2$, so the limit doesn't exist. (Though, if we allow fractional $q<1$, the ratio $x_{n+1}/x_n^q$ converges to $0$.)

Are you requiring $x_n$ and $y_n$ to have the same order of convergence $q$, and the same rate $\mu$? Here's another example: $$x_n=-a\cdot r^n,\qquad y_n=b\cdot s^n,\qquad a,b,r,s>0,\qquad r,s<1$$ $$\frac{x_{n+1}-0}{x_n-0}\to r,\qquad \frac{y_{n+1}-0}{y_n-0}\to s$$ $$\frac{y_{n+1}-x_{n+1}}{y_n-x_n}=\frac{a\cdot r^{n+1}+b\cdot s^{n+1}}{a\cdot r^n+b\cdot s^n}\to\max(r,s)$$

I do assume that they have the same order of convergence. The thing is, I am looking for justification for computing the limit $\frac{y_{n+1} - x_{n+1}}{(y_n - x_n)^q}$ instead of $\frac{y_{n+1} - L}{(y_n - L)^q}$ since, especially in the case of the AGM, the limit $L$ is much harder to access. And I also want to know if this can be generalised to other (pairs of) sequences.

@AlexRavsky (it should be proven that) $q$ should be the order of convergence of both $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ when the limit of $\frac{y_{n+1}-x_{n+1}}{(y_n-x_n)^q}$ is between 0 and 1.

I expect this is false, for instance, when the sequence $(y_n)$ has the order of convergence $q$ and the rate of convergence $\mu$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac {x_n-L}{y_n-L}=0$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac {y_{n+1}-x_{n+1}}{(y_n-x_n)^q}=\mu$, but the sequence $(x_n)$ can converge to $L$ very fast.

Well, my latter example already shows that it's not true, at least for $q=1$. Take $r>s$, so the ratio $(y_{n+1}-x_{n+1})/(y_n-x_n)$ converges to $r$, but $(y_{n+1}-L)/(y_n-L)$ converges to $s$ instead. Still it might be true for $q>1$. -- Concerning the AGM, you should only care about the order $q\overset?=2$, not the rate $\mu$.

In fact it's not true for $q>1$ either, as shown by modifying that example: $$x_n=-a\cdot r^{q^n},\qquad y_n=b\cdot s^{q^n},\qquad a,b,r,s>0,\qquad r,s<1$$ $$\frac{|x_{n+1}-0|}{|x_n-0|^q}\to a^{1-q},\qquad\frac{|y_{n+1}-0|}{|y_n-0|^q}\to b^{1-q}$$ $$\frac{|y_{n+1}-x_{n+1}|}{|y_n-x_n|^q}=\frac{a\cdot(r^{q^n})^q+b\cdot(s^{q^n})^q}{(a\cdot r^{q^n}+b\cdot s^{q^n})^q}\to\begin{cases}a^{1-q},\quad\text{if}\quad r>s\ b^{1-q},\quad\text{if}\quad r<s\ (a+b)^{1-q},\quad\text{if}\quad r=s\end{cases}$$
